# Unable to access another computer by computer name

Tags: networking, connection

I am having a Laptop with vista premium. I have setup wireless connection. I am having BSNL ADSL Modem for broadband and also i am using it as a wireless router from router i had connected one port to my linksys router which was connected to another computer in my network. I had also one wired connection which direcly connect to linksys router.

My query:
Initially I am able to connect to another computer in lan through wireless connection by since last one month I am unable to connect. So for lan connection I have to join wired and for internet connection of BSNL I have to connect wireless. I am unable to see to another computer in lan when wireless connection was done. Many time it was happen that to connect another computer I have to use ip adderss because by computername I am not able to connect. 
Kindly sove my problem or mail me on jhaverijk@yahoo.com urgently.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Has anything changed in your network setup within that time frame? I'd check the NetBIOS settings to start.

Right-click your connection and select **properties**, then select **Internet Protocol (TCP/IP)** and hit **properties** once again. Click the **Advanced** button and navigate to the **WINS** tab. Near the bottom, ensure NetBIOS is not disabled like this:

[image]

What you want essentially is to enable NetBIOS over TCP/IP:

[image]