# Can access computers on local network by IP address, but not by computer name

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, networking, home-networking

On my local network, I can type the IP address of a computer like so: \\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx and access the shared files/printers of that computer.

But when I try by computer name, it does not let me.  Any reason why?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/q/104075/179299

Comment: tried that and it did not work

Comment: How are you expecting it to work?

Comment: As stated above, I want to be able to type \\computer-name and be able to access shared  files/printers of that computer.  At this moment, accessing shared files/printers of a computer only works when I type ip address like this: \\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Comment: What have you done to make the computers "know" each other's names?  Do you have DNS configured?  `hosts` files?

Comment: From experience in the past, whenever I joined the same workgroup of a set of windows computers on a network, I was always able to simply type the computer-name and access that computers shared files/printers.  When you say "Do you have DNS configured?", what do you actually mean?

Comment: DNS stands for Domain Name System; when configuring a connection to a network you need IP, netmask, gateway. For extra functionality: DNS (network names and WAN names you need DNS).

Comment: Yes I understand, but as of now I have DHCP enabled through my router, so I obtain automatically.  Does the router need to be configured somehow to accomplish what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: a lot of routers have their own DNS servers and since your DHCP is enabled, chances are DNS service router-side is enabled as well.

Comment: So what could be the problem?

Comment: DNS is router dependent.  My first modem/router had a DNS server, although sometimes it took a while to register/advertise  a host name.  A replacement modem/router does not have DNS.  So now I have to look up the assigned IP address in order to do a `ping` from Linux machines.  But Windows7 PCs have Link-Layer Discovery protocol, and WinXP seems to rely on File & Printer Sharing. Are those Windows services enabled on your PCs?

Comment: Check your hosts file. Make sure the computer(s)is using the DNS dished out by your router and not pointing else where (static) and enable NetBIOS over IP/TCP. Does the same error persist in a PING?

Comment: File & Printer Sharing is enabled. PING does not work with computer-name, but does work with IP address.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How access network computers by name](http://superuser.com/questions/81547/how-access-network-computers-by-name)

Comment: Not quite a duplicate. The OPs PCs are all Windows. As long as they are in the same workgroup, they should all be accessible by name because NETBIOS publishes the computer name. If I remember rightly, one of the computers will be designated as the "master browser" to control all that. It does, however, sometimes take a long time for all of the PC's to catch up with each other.

Comment: All PCs have been on the same network for quite some time now, yet computer-names between all PCs are still not recognized.

Comment: It's weird. Now I can ping a computer-name, but if I try to do an nslookup on that computer-name it will say: "*** UnKnown can't find (computer-name): Non-existent domain"

Comment: I am using a DLink TL-WR940N wireless router which has DHCP.  I looked for NetBIOS settings on the actual router, but I could not find any.
I am convinced that the Computer-Name problem I 'm having is being caused by my wireless network hosted by my DLink router.
I have upgraded firmware, restored defaults, and I am using a very simple, almost default, setup on my DLink router.
Any suggestions where to go from here?

Answer (score -1):

Easiest fix is you edit your hosts file (%windows%\system32\drivers\etc) in your favorite text editor to add the other machines on your network in the following format:

IP     HOSTNAME (IP and hostname need to be separated by at least one space (I use a single tab)

Save and exit and you should be good.

Comment: This is _not_ a good fix if the network is using DHCP.

Comment: Actually, it is.  Most home use routers in my experience assign the same IP to a host.

Comment: No its not @Sarge, you cannot guarantee that the IP will stay the same. If it does stay the same for a while, that's even worse as it's easy for people to forget changes made to the HOSTS file. Most routers allow MAC addresses to be assigned a fixed IP under DHCP which fixes that part but that doesn't resolve the fact that this *should* work without hacks.